# Installing Schwinn Vestige frame LED cable

Tags: frames, dynamo, led-lights

I read a post (Daniel and Jennifer) from a couple of years ago explaining that the Vestige frame LED should be replaced if it is no longer working.  Thanks for that. Now, I'm seeking tips, a guide or a manual on how to install the new light string so it will work properly.  Mine is not. Dynamo has been tested and works fine.

I do a lot of bike repairs but this one is a big challenge.

[image: Stock image of a vestige]

Comment: I assumed the LEDs were outside the frame, but they're inside, and because the frame is made from "flax fibre" its translucent.   Are all the LEDs dead?  That implies a wiring fault, a break somewhere.   Can you see any wires anywhere in the path?   I'd be most suspicious of the bends near the headset, because they will flex the most.

Comment: If you can't get to any wires, perhaps it would be easiest to connect the dynamo to some EL wire, and simply rig that on the frame instead?   Ugly dirty hack, or simply fit normal bike lights and do away with the glowing inside the frame ?

Comment: Sorry, but removing the seat post doesn't help as the vertical tube has no opening to the two tubes which contain the LEDs so the string idea doesn't work.

Comment: How did you test the dynamo?  Was there access to the wiring via a plug, to allow the wheel to be removed?

Comment: For what it's worth I found a site on E-Bay that repairs the lights. He states "Send the entire string along with the control cube". Based on that I would assume failure is common. The repair may require soldering or component replacement on the controller.

Answer (score 3):

I would start by pulling the seatpost, fork and the bottom bracket. Use a small mirror similar to a Dentists type to try to see if the wire is attached in the frame or just passes thru. You may then be able to remove it. If possible attach a string to the end of the cable. You can then use the string to pull the repaired light cable back through the frame.

Comment: Sorry, but removing the seat post doesn't help as the vertical tube has no opening to the two tubes which contain the LEDs so the string idea doesn't work.